# Javascript/Three.js one million iterations loop performance

Tags: javascript, performance, loops, three.js

I have this javascript code that i need to run once for generating a grid of quadrants from a 3d object imported from blender (it is a three.js project).
The problem is that it runs a loop of about 1 million iterations and happens that the script takes a long time and then crashes. 
To be precise, there are 10,000 iterations in which, each time, a mesh is generated and then a further loop of 121 raycaster.intersectObjects is executed.
What I would like to know if this script is really so demanding for an Intel i7-7800x CPU or if the problem depends on something else, such as browser memory or setting (I tested with all the browsers).

```
    var scene= new THREE.Scene();

    renderer= new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight); 
    renderer.setClearColor (0xf9f9f9, 1);
    renderer.gammaOutput= true;
    renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
    renderer.shadowMap.enabled= true;
    renderer.shadowMap.type= THREE.PCFSoftShadowMap;
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    var light= new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1.4, 100);
    light.position.set(3, 2, 0);
    light.castShadow= true;
    scene.add(light);
    light.shadow.mapSize.width= 512; 
    light.shadow.mapSize.height= 512;
    light.shadow.camera.near= 0.5;
    light.shadow.camera.far= 500;

    var camera= new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, 
    window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 100000);
    camera.position.set(0, 70, 70);
    camera.lookAt(0, 0, 0);

    var controls= new THREE.OrbitControls(camera);

    var loader= new THREE.GLTFLoader();
    loader.load(
        'http://localhost/planegeometryeditor/meshes/map/map_def.gltf', 
        function(gltf) {
            gltf.scene.receiveShadow= true;
            scene.add(gltf.scene);
            scene.children[1].rotation.y= -(Math.PI/2);
            var sceneobjs= scene.children[1].children;
            for(var iobj in sceneobjs) {
                var obj= sceneobjs[iobj];
                obj.updateMatrixWorld();
                if(obj.name== 'terrain') { 
                   var terrain= obj; 
                   for(var tmindex in terrain.children[0].children) { 
                       terrain.children[0].children[tmindex].material.side= 
                       THREE.DoubleSide; 
                   }
                 }
                if(obj.name.search('tree')!= -1) { obj.name= 'tree' }
            }
            var terrain_bbox = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(terrain);
            var terrain_position= terrain.position;

            //------------ LOOP -----------------------
            //-----------------------------------------

            var idquad= 0;
            for(var i= -49.5; i<=49.5; i= i+1) {
                for(var ii= -49.5; ii<=49.5; ii= ii+1) {

                    var idquad= idquad+1;
                    var quadgeo= new THREE.PlaneGeometry(1,1);
                    var quadmat= new 
                    THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color:0x00ff00, side: 
                    THREE.DoubleSide});
                    var quad= new THREE.Mesh(quadgeo, quadmat);
                    quad.name= 'quad-'+idquad;
                    scene.add(quad);
                    quad.rotation.x= -(Math.PI/2);
                    quad.position.x= i;
                    quad.position.y= -5;
                    quad.position.z= ii;

                    for(var a= (i-0.5); a<=(i+0.5); a= 
                     Number((a+0.1).toFixed(2))) {
                        for(var aa= (ii-0.5); aa<=(ii+0.5); aa= 
                        Number((aa+0.1).toFixed(2))) {
                            var raycaster= new THREE.Raycaster();
                            var rorigin= new THREE.Vector3(a, -5, aa);
                            var rdirection= new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 0);
                            raycaster.set(rorigin, rdirection);
                            var intersects= 
                            raycaster.intersectObjects(scene.children, 
                            true);
                        }
                    }

                }
            }

            //------------ LOOP -----------------------
            //-----------------------------------------

        }, // success
        undefined, 
        function (error) { console.error(error); }
    );

    render();
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? One quick suggestion is to avoid creating new objects at all inside a loop (reuse the material, geometry, raycaster, vectors, etc). Raycasting can also be intensive, especially with so many objects in the scene. If you're just trying to raycast against planes it would probably be best to do so using math functions instead of creating new Meshes.

Comment: The crash report should be more specific, but given how many objects you are creating there yes I'd guess it's running out of memory.

Comment: To answer your question, yes, your script is very demanding. There's got to be a more efficient way to create your geometry. All those individual meshes and materials are so similar, that you should be able to use InstancedBufferGeometry: https://threejs.org/examples/?q=instancing#webgl_buffergeometry_instancing Also, why are you re-creating the same geometry and material 10,000 times? If they're exactly the same, you should just use the same one.

Comment: Garrett Johnson I'm trying to create a grid of quadrants below a terrain. The goal is to save inside each object information related to the portion of terrain that is exactly above.
Bergi What do you mean by memory?
Marquizzo The meshes are not all the same, they differ in position and then I need to assign different properties to each of them.
Thanks for pointing out the Instancing, I think it can be crucial to lighten the script, even if, excluding the raycaster loop, the script, although taking several minutes, ends correctly, so the problem remains the raycaster loop .